# Diagonalize matrix full of $1/n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $K$ be a field whose characteristic does not divide $n$. Consider the $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $K$
>   $$
> A=\frac{1}{n}\begin{pmatrix}1&\cdots&1\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   a) Show that $A$ is idempotent, that is, $A^2=A$.
>
> b) Find an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix. Specify $S$ and the diagonal matrix explicity.

**My thoughts:**

So for part ($a$), should I just do it directly by computing the entries of $A^2$ via the sum formula? This seems a bit tedious, and I am curious if there is a better way. For part ($b$), I know diagonalization typically requires finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I don't quite see a nice way to do that here. Any advice?

Comment: Calculating the entries of $A^2$ really isn't tedious.

Comment: Neither is finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying not to solve it for you, but here are some hints.

(a) It is difficult to find a method easier than straightforward computation here.

(b) Notice that (a) gives you a polynomial equation for which $A$ is a solution. It is not hard to see that this also describes the minimal polynomial of $A$, so factoring it gives you all eigenvalues for $A$. The rank of $A$ is also readily seen, so you can deduce the dimension of the eigenspaces. Lastly, the less tedious way I see to find eigenvectors is to realize that by writing the solution for (a) somehow hinted at what kind of non-trivial eigenvectors you could find.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $$\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^n+\beta_1\lambda^{n-1}+...+\beta_n$$ we have $$\beta_i=(-1)^i\text{ sum of principal minors of $A$ of order $i$.}$$ Thus $$\beta_1=-1, \beta_i=0 \text{ for }i>1.$$ Thus the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $$\lambda^n-\lambda^{n-1}=\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda-1).$$ The eigenvalues are 0 and 1. A basis for the eigenspace for eigenvalue 0 is $$\{\mathbf {v_1, ... ,v_{n-1}}\}$$ where $\mathbf v_i$ is the column-vector whose entries in positions $i$ and $i+1$ are -1 and 1 respectively and whose other entries are all 0. A basis for the eigenspace for eigenvalue 0 is $\{\mathbf v\}$ where $\mathbf v$ is the column vector whose entries are all 1. Let $S$ be the matrix whose $i-$th column is $\mathbf v_i$ for $1 \le i \le n-1$ and whose $n-$th column is $\mathbf v.$ Then 
$$S^{-1}AS=D$$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is (0, ... ,0,1).